# java.lang.IllegalStateException error with Firebase Analytics

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Analytics in my application and after adding that to my project I'm getting this error in `logcat` after application starts. I've searched for it but I found nothing to fix it and I'm not using SQLite database in my application. What is wrong?

```
E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/data/user/0/ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc/databases/google_app_measurement_local.db' is not open.
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.throwIfNotOpenLocked(SQLiteDatabase.java:2185)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.createSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:367)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue(SQLiteDatabase.java:86)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.initialValue(SQLiteDatabase.java:85)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:160)
              at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:150)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.getThreadSession(SQLiteDatabase.java:361)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.getSession(SQLiteProgram.java:101)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.setLastStmt(SQLiteQuery.java:96)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.close(SQLiteQuery.java:111)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.close(SQLiteCursor.java:300)
              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.finalize(SQLiteCursor.java:366)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:222)
              at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:209)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

this is my app module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.aftabeshafa.shafadoc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.2.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: Post your gradle file

Comment: check my post again @Raghavendra

Comment: I'm not using sqlite database in my application! @RaviPrakashVerma

Comment: I think u have already checked the related posts.. Did u try with downgrading firebase dependency to 9.6.0 and try with that once?

Comment: This looks more like a Firebase bug - they are misusing sqlite database somehow.

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting the same log again @Raghavendra

Comment: But I don't found any report or same problem  @dimsuz

Comment: Just for a test case can u uninstall existing app and install it freshly and try once.?

Comment: yes I dead that many times @Raghavendra

Comment: @Amir_P may be "completely unnecessary" but try put "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" outside dependencies block and try:)

Comment: it doesn't work I'm still getting that error every 1-2 minutes @Raghavendra

Comment: @Amir_P I too don't the soln dude:( can u post this in google forum if u didn't get the soln here.

Comment: @Amir_P Update here if u get the soln.

Comment: Does your `logcat` include any messages like this: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`?

Comment: there is no log like that @qbix